# Two-factor ID and Find My Phone app

Tags: google-account, google-authenticator

After enabling two-factor identification on my google account, I lost my android (Samsung 9) phone, so I tried to use the Find My Phone app on a friend's phone. Of course, the two-factor ID correctly prevented me from being able to use that app to find my phone.

I found my phone this time, but in the futue I would like to be able to use Find My Phone app on another device, authenticating myself with two-factor ID still enabled. I'm sure there is a way to do this, perhaps by pre-authenticating myself on Google Authenticator on my PC or a friend's phone, so in the future I can Find My Phone but others cannot. Please help! Thanks.

Siirandler

Comment: With activate 2FA you should prepare a backup code for Google: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1187538?&hl=en